# Were airworthiness certificates revoked for B737 Max?

Tags: boeing-737, airworthiness

Following up from [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/73585/what-is-the-difference-between-type-certificate-and-certificate-of-airworthin) - or more specifically Brian Drummond's comment on the accepted answer:

> Or even revoked without modification, if something new is discovered about the existing components (e.g. failure modes)

When B737 Max were grounded due to suspected issues with MCAS, what happened to the Certificates of Airworthiness of individual aircraft?  Technically speaking,

> something new [has been] discovered about the existing component

Per the quoted comment, this could result in the certificates being revoked.  Did it actually happen? If not, what formal measures exist that prevent somebody flying a B737 Max? (Other than common sense of course.)

Comment: Can anyone at least speak to whether this question gets the premise right? Would an airworthiness certificate be revoked if the entire model is grounded? It seems like an AC is for a specific plane, and I'm not sure if that would necessarily be taken away due to the grounding of the entire fleet.

Comment: @zymhan That's actually a good point. I'm not sure whether the type certificate can be revoked, but in this case that could possibly be the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The grounding of the 737max is a [Prohibition of Operation](https://www.faa.gov/news/updates/media/Emergency_Order.pdf), not a revocation of Type Certificate. This is done by each jurisdiction around the world. China suspended flights two days before the FAA did.

Technically, if you could find a country that never prohibited its flight, the Max could still be used there. Repositioning flights of grounded aircraft, as to a storage location, are authorized on a case by case basis.